# Shared maximum eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvector

Let us consider two arbitrary Hermitian square matrices $\mathbf{A,B}$ with the same dimension. Given $\mathbf{v}$ the eigenvector associated to the maximum eigenvalue of $\mathbf{A}$:

> Are there any conditions appart from $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{B}$ or $\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{v}\mathbf{v}^H$ so that it can be ensured that $\mathbf{B}$ has the same eigenvector associated to the maximum eigenvalue?

Note that, in Dan Shemesh, Common eigenvectors of two matrices, Linear Algebra and its Applications, Volume 62, November 1984, Pages 11-18, ISSN 0024-3795, http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795(84)90085-5. an arbitrary eigenvector was considered. I cross check the derivation, and I do not see how to promote the maximum eigenvector constraint.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The question is unclear. Are they real matrices? (Otherwise what do you mean by "largest" --- largest in absolute value?) What kind of condition would you want?

Comment: Thank you Nik, I add the condition of A and B being Hermitian. I look for a more 'exhaustive' condition rather than the ones I metion in the question.

Comment: One such condition is that (for normal matrices) $\| AB\| = \| A \| \cdot \|B\|$ (where obviously we take the $2-2$ norm).

Comment: @DavidHandelman: maybe require $A$ and $B$ to be positive? I'm unsure whether the "maximum" eigenvalue is allowed to be negative ...

Comment: $A$, $B$ are only required to be Hermitian. With this, the eigenvalues are always real, then there are no worries about the ordering.

Comment: @DavidHandelman: This is not correct: $A=\textrm{diag}(1,0)$, $B=-A$ is a counterexample.

Comment: I erred; I meant to say that if $A$ and $B$ are normal matrices and $\|AB\| = \| A \| \cdot \|B \|$, then $A$ and $B$ share a common eigenvector for at least one pair of eigenvalues of maximal absolute value (one for $A$, the other for $B$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true iff the largest eigenvalue of $A+B$ is the sum of that of $A$ and that of $B$.

Comment: Could you elaborate your response a little?

Comment: For an appropriate interpretation of the question, at least.  The OP said $v$ is "the" eigenvector associated to the maximum eigenvalue of $A$, but if the eigenspace is not 1-dimensional you may need to replace $v$ with another eigenvector.